# SVG inside flex misaligned when wrapped in div

Tags: html, css, svg, flexbox

I want an SVG icon of unknown size center aligned to the left of some text. I preferably want to use flex.

This is the CSS for the SVG and text container:

```
.container {
    background-color: pink;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    margin: 10px;
    width: 200px;
}
```

---

This works fine:

```
<div class="container">
  <svg style="width:24px;height:24px" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
    <rect width="24" height="24"/>
  </svg>
  <div>ALIGNED ICON</div>
</div>
```

However, when I wrap the SVG in another `div`, the height of that `div` becomes unnecessarily big, resulting in a misalignment of the SVG and text:

```
<div class="container">
    <div>
        <svg style="width:24px;height:24px" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
            <rect width="24" height="24"/>
        </svg>
    </div>
    <div>MISALIGNED ICON</div>
</div>
```

Here is a link to [CodePen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/JxxxNE)

---

In reality, this is a React project and I use external SVG components that I don't have control over or know the size of. I can therefore not apply any styles directly to the SVG element, neither set the wrapper `div` height to match that of the SVG.

**How do I align the SVG and text when wrapping the SVG in another div?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The inner div must be displayed as [flex](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/CSS/flex) as well

Check this [demo](https://tools.waytolearnx.com/html-viewer/ad76af7c1db4).

```css
.container {
  background-color: pink;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 10px;
  width: 200px; 
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <svg style="width:24px;height:24px" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
    <rect width="24" height="24"/>
  </svg>
  <div>ALIGNED SVG</div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div style="display: flex;">
    <svg style="width:24px;height:24px" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
      <rect width="24" height="24"/>
    </svg>
  </div>
  <div>MISALIGNED SVG</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, that works. Any documentation on why this is needed?

Answer (score 4):

Just add flex and align to that div class.

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/zeeegz

**html**

```
<div class="container">
  <svg style="width:24px;height:24px" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
    <rect width="24" height="24"/>
  </svg>
  <div>ALIGNED SVG</div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">
    <svg style="width:24px;height:24px" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
      <rect width="24" height="24"/>
    </svg>
  </div>
  <div>MISALIGNED SVG</div>
</div>
```

**css**

```
 .container {
      background-color: pink;
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
      margin: 10px;
      width: 200px;
    }
    .item{
      display: flex;

    }
```

Comment: Thanks, that works. Any documentation on why this is needed?